# Can NGINX be used with one domain but serve different sub-directories from different locations

Tags: nginx

I will try and break this down as best as possible.

We have domain.com

What we would like is 2 servers in different locations eg UK & US

We would like the user to see domain.com/uk/ or domain.com/us/ and each to serve it's own content.

We could use uk.domain.com or us.domain.com with their own ip addresses but our domain reads a lot better with the forward-slash version.

Our issue is first time byte.

We don't want users in the US to have to check the DNS on a UK server only to be sent back to the US or vice versa.

Is there a way to achieve this in Nginx?

Comment: You should probably be looking for a CDN. You cannot achieve this using a single domain name and regular DNS.

Comment: A CDN, or anycast, or give up and use subdomains.